How to call a stored procedure in Entity Framework Core 7.0 that returns a result set which is not an actual table in the database?
I'm working on a project using Entity Framework Core 7.0, and I need to call a stored procedure that returns a result set which doesn't correspond to an actual table in the database. The stored procedure returns a custom class or a result set that doesn't have a corresponding entity mapped in my DbContext.
How can I call such a stored procedure and retrieve the result set using Entity Framework Core 7.0?
Details:
I'm using Entity Framework Core 7.0. The stored procedure I need to call returns a result set that doesn't map to an existing table/entity in my database schema.
I want to retrieve the result set and map it to a custom class in my application.
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

According to your description, if you want to use the SP in ef core and auto binding, you should add it inside your dbcontext and set it with the OnModelCreating.
More details, you could refer to below example:
My test SP:
-- Create a stored procedure named Test
CREATE PROCEDURE TestResults
AS
BEGIN
    -- Select some custom data
    SELECT 
        1 AS Id,
        'First Result' AS Name

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        2 AS Id,
        'Second Result' AS Name

  
END

Model class:
public class TestResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Dbcontext:
public DbSet<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<TestResult>(entity =>
entity.HasKey(e => e.Id));
 }

Usage:
        var result = _applicationDbContext.TestResults.FromSqlInterpolated($"[dbo].[TestResults]").ToList();

Result:



But when I'll run the migration it will create a table in the database. How can I avoid that? Also my class doesn't have any ID property

Try this :
     public DbSet<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Necessary, since our model isnt a EF model
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestResult>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);

    }


But when I'll run the migration it will create a table in the database. How can I avoid that? Also my class doesn't have any ID property

Please try my update works, this will not create the table and it works well inside the applicationdbcontext.

You can use configuration like this instead of @Brando Zhang config to avoid migrations to create a new unexpected table.
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestResult>()
            .HasNoKey()
            .ToView(null);

P/s: I have low reputation to add comment :)
